# Retrieve image from url then rename with datestamp to local folder every minute

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, cron, wget

I'm new to command line on my ubuntu s3 micro instance and I need a cron job that grabs an image every minute and renames it to datestamp.jpg in a folder... example:

get this url: http://www.webcam1.com/live.jpg 
rename to year_month_day_hour_min_second.jpg
save to cams/webcam1/

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one command:

```
wget "http://www.webcam1.com/live.jpg" -O `date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.jpg"`
```

If you are doing this from a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/cams/webcam1/"
now=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.jpg"`
wget "http://www.webcam1.com/live.jpg" -O "$dir$now"
```

Save that bash script somewhere, and make sure to make it executable: `chmod +x /path/to/my/script.sh`

And then add this line to your crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

And that should do it :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer! Everything is working except the file name ends up as: 
    date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.jpg"

I'm currently using the following in my bash script:
`now='date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.jpg"'`

What corrections do you recommend to get the datestamp working properly? Thanks very much!

Comment: @user427687: you are using single quotes: `'` instead of a backtick: `\``

Comment: Thanks! it is working..... I've got another variation if you have an extra moment...  Would I need to write the script any different if my cam url contained special characters like the following: 

http://mywebcam.dyndns.org:90/cgi-bin/encoder?USER=Admin&PWD=123456&SNAPSHOT=N640x480,100&DUMMY=

Thanks again for your expertise!